# Why do pidgeys and rattatas still appear even if not in sightings?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why do some Pokemon still appear even if the sightings prompt doesn't show them?

Answer (score 4):

There are more possibilties:

1. Your data in the tracker is not synchronized yet, but the information for the pidgey is already downloaded.
2. It just spawned there.
3. The list is already full with other Pokémon (can happen, probably not with pidgey or rattata but though).

When you reopen the App with a good Internet connection the tracker should be loaded accurately.

Comment: I would imagine the tracker does not update at the rate that actual spawns do, to reduce network load.  They have already moved a lot of flavors like footprints, caught locations, just to deal with the massive load.

I have had rare Pokemons show up even though it was not on the list.  Caught two Dratini that way.